# Embed Complete GitHub Repository in a Web Page

Tags: plugins, github, github-api

I have created a repository on Github. This repository contains a complete project with the folder structure and files. If I have to embed this code on my website, I can do that by creating Gists and adding them to my web page.

The problem is that I have a big project and adding snippets as Gists is not an easy task; also, it will not be user friendly either, as the visitors won't get the idea of the complete project.

So, I just want to embed the whole repository on my web page in such a way that the visitor can browse the code. Do you have any idea about that? Any API, Plug In, code sample etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JQuery plugin was recently created that adds this functionality.  Take a look a [repo.js](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js).