# How to embed code from repo in github markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

Is there a way of embedding the content of a file (from the projects repo) in Githubs markdown?

I have a code sample and want to embed it in the projects readme.

Comment: sorry, my english is not that good. Do you want to put a piece of code in the readme which is in Markdown format, is that it ?

Comment: @BernardoFire no. I want to link to a checked in code file and have the contents of that file rendered when the markdown is viewed

Comment: Check this link. Looks like there is a jquery plugin for showing an entire repo in a website. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316499/embed-complete-github-repository-in-a-web-page

Comment: The ability to do this would allow greatly improved github READMEs, more correctness and less maintenance. I get that its non-trivial, but cmon Microsoft, you can do this!

Comment: If you want to try something for documentation outside of Github, Sourcegraph has private or public [Notebooks](https://sourcegraph.com/notebooks?tab=getting-started) that are basically markdown with really nice embedded code blocks and hyperlinking. Example: [Tour de Source of Caddy](https://sourcegraph.com/notebooks/Tm90ZWJvb2s6MTM2Nw==)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

It turns out this is now possible if you paste a permalink of the code in your `README.md` file.

To figure out how to get the permalink, check [GitHub's docs on the topic](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet). The permalink and the `README.md` needs to be in the same repository.

OLD ANSWER:

You can't do that currently. You will have to copy your code sample and paste it between triple ticks in your README file. Here is an example:

````
``` Ruby
class MyClass
end
```
````

This will be static of course and you must update it manually when that code changes.

Comment: is this still the case in 2017?

Comment: @ThiagoSilva I believe so, yes.

Comment: Late 2020 checking in -- still the case? Has Microsoft come to the rescue here? My guess, it being 2020, is no.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada I have been trying to use this github action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/markdown-embed-code-from-file
It is supposed to do the trick, using "```cpp:path/to/file.cpp```". However, I haven't managed to set it up on my own repo.

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler this is a nice pointer to the fact GitHub Actions can be used to keep parts of your content dynamic like that. The GitHub Action needs to work of course, and if it doesn't there may be something with the setup or even a bug in how the action behaves. I may need to update my original answer .

Comment: Thank you Petros :) The github actions I previously refered to (markdown-embed-code-from-file) did not work for me, but I found another action (mardown-autodocs) that does the job perfectly (even if a bit more verbose). I explained it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584456/10360134)!

Comment: Aug 2022 edit. Please see Utkarsh's answer below for correct answer

Answer (score 20):

@Petros's answer is (still) correct, however I got annoyed enough with this that I've created a tool to automate the copying and keep your readme synchronised with the source - https://github.com/zakhenry/embedme

Example usage from the accepted answer

Insert a comment into the code fence

````
```rb
# path/to/your/file.rb
```
````

Run `npx embedme README.md` (this assumes you have Nodejs installed)

The README will be written in-place, with the content of the file following your comment

````
```rb
# path/to/your/file.rb
class MyClass
end
```
````

Note that as the comment is still there, you can happily re-run `npx embedme README.md` again and it won't make any change.

If you have CI, you can also run `npx embedme --verify README.md` which will return `1` if it detects a diff (this would mean that the source was updated without the readme being updated).

Answer (score 6):

Github now supports rendering permalink in markdown files. example - https://github.com/stevemar/code-reference-in-readme

credit: https://www.stevemar.net/github-code-in-readme/

Comment: found the same result searching...is there  a way to do this so it renders in VSCode's markdown preview as well as in github once uploaded?

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use github actions, I found [Markdown autodocs](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/markdown-autodocs) on Github Marketplace to work for my project.

All you have to do is to add a line in your `.github/workflows/your-workflow.yml` file:

```
uses: dineshsonachalam/markdown-autodocs@v1.0.4
```

Then insert these snippets in your Markdown files:

```
<!-- MARKDOWN-AUTO-DOCS:START (CODE:src=./relative/path/to/code.js) -->
<!-- MARKDOWN-AUTO-DOCS:END -->
```

I also like the fact that it allows for remote files to be used:

```
<!-- MARKDOWN-AUTO-DOCS:START (CODE:src=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/project/master/path/to/file) -->
<!-- MARKDOWN-AUTO-DOCS:END -->
```

And also the fact that you can restrict the number of lines printed:

```
<!-- MARKDOWN-AUTO-DOCS:START (CODE:src=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/project/master/path/to/file&lines=1-42) -->
<!-- MARKDOWN-AUTO-DOCS:END -->
```

Comment: Just tried it, pretty cool! thanks :)

Comment: It's a shame that https://github.com/marketplace/actions/markdown-embed-code-from-file doesn't work, since the syntax is more pleasant. But at least there's something we can use.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a script that will load the source code from a public repo and then show it within the container. Here is an example of an MD file which loads data from github and displays that within a container.

```
## Welcome to the Simple Alarm Server Example
This page will load and show a code example. 


<div id="code-element"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
      axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iotify/nsim-examples/master/functional-testing/alarm-server.js'
       })
      .then(function (response) {
         document.getElementById("code-element").innerHTML = response.data;
      });
</script>
```